# what is the differenc between these two "statments" in desciption logic

Tags: logic, owl, description-logic

I don't know if you call this **statement** or not, but I have this question

what is the difference between these two `statments` :

```
A ⊑ B ⊓ C
```

and

```
A ASSERTA_SYMBOL =  B ⊓ C
```

sorry I don't know how to write the ASSERTA_SYMBOL, but it is in this image

[image]

a real example is this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Both expressions describe or define a concept (or class or set).

The difference is subclass vs equivalent class.

An elephant is one kind of grey, large animals. There might be other kinds.
A happy father is a man who has at least one daughter and any man with at least one daughter is a happy father. There are no others.

Comment: I don't think that "define" is quite the right word for a subclass relationship.  It's stating necessary conditions, but it's hardly a definition.  "Human" is a subclass of "Biped", but it's not right to say that the "Humans are Bipeds" is a definition.

Answer (score 1):

⊑ represents a subconcept relationship, ≐ means agreement (sometimes called the *same as* constructor).